# Fail to get the statistics of https video using ffprobe

Tags: http, https, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I want to collect the statistics of a video stream backed by https url.

on executing 
ffprobe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbYjtSFa5Fs

I get the following output

```
vagrant@kaybus:/vagrant/kaybus$ ffprobe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbYjtSFa5Fs
ffprobe version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[tls @ 0x3547140] A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbYjtSFa5Fs: Input/output error
```

[tls @ 0x3547140] A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
How to fix the above error?

https is listed in ffprobe's supported input and output protocols.

ffprobe -version

```
vagrant@kaybus:/vagrant/kaybus$ ffprobe -version
ffprobe version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is a typical web site: it is not a direct link to a video. `ffprobe` supports HTTP(S), but it is not an HTML parser.